# How to find the torque required to rotate wooden slab

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, electrical

How can I find the Torque needed to rotate a wooden slab with no weight applied on either end of the slab if I have a servo motor placed at the middle of the slab?
[image: diagram that shows a wooden slab connected to a motor]

Comment: Do you need to rotate it fast or slow? Does it accelerate? If yes what is the maximum acceleration?

Comment: And what you expect the running friction of the system to be.  A 5kg beam on smooth roller bearings would take very little force to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torque is equal to angular acceleration times moment of inertia of your board, idealized to$ \ 1/12mL^2$.

There are interesting points to check for though.

Whit a small defect in symmetry your board can turn into a propeller and create a lift.

If the face thickness is not insignificant the whirling of the air current can become very complex.